Python Kivy APK File shows loading screen for three seconds and then crashes
This is our first time making an app using Python and Kivy (and coding in general). We used Python, Kivy, Google Colab, and Buildozer to make this app. After different trials and errors, we managed to successfully convert it to an APK. However, when we installed the APK on our phones and opened our app, it just showed a loading screen for three seconds and it automatically exited. We couldn't identify what the problem is  (hopefully y'all could help us). Here are all of the relevant files.
Python Kivy APK File shows loading screen for three seconds and then crashes
We tried different tools like Buildozer, Google Colab, and GitHub but so far, it only worked once on Google Colab and Buildozer

Try running buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt with your phone attached to your PC via a USB cable. Then look in my_log.txt for hints.

Also, you can try the APK in an android emulator before on your mobile. In order to exclude if it is a problem with the phone or with the application.
